# How to manipulate this string in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this string `PREFIX:ABR`. I would like to manipulate it such that it becomes `ABR:NEW_PREFIX`. How can this be done in Excel VBA?

Comment: This question already has an answer. Why the downvote? Please tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the `Split` function:

```
InputString = "PREFIX:ABR"
InputArray = Split(InputString, ":")
OutputString = InputArray(1) & ":NEW_" & InputArray(0)
```